# How to export configuration of maas (Metal as a service)

Tags: maas

For a few days, I have performed some tests of automatic tool deployment of Canonical: Maas. I think it's very promising. But how can I save my configuration? And, if I have one save, how can I import it?  For instance, to make a migration from a maas1.9 to maas 2.0.

I have not found anything on the internet, and the `maas cli` command `maas user maas get-config` doesn't help.